# Two sets of Jquery cody on a one-page HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a one-page HTML page that has anchors as menu items. I found code that will help ease the transition to the anchors throughout the page. Here is the code for a smooth transition:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
            $(function() {
              $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
                if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                  var target = $(this.hash);
                  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                  if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                      scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1500);
                    return false;
                  }
                }
              });
            });

        </script>
```

`
Part way down my one-page HTML page, I want to use the tabs jquery code to display information. My problem is that because of the transition jquery code (above), there's seems to be a problem with the tabs jquery (code below). Sometimes, after clicking on the tab, the functions above don't work. My ChrisPederick tool bar is not showing any JavaScript errors. I would really appreciate any input on how to fix this problem.

Below is the code for my tabs javascript. Currently, the tabs javascript in my one-page HTML page is located directly before my tabs div, meaning the javascript code is in the `<body>` tag:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Alcohol &amp; College Life</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Financial Fitness</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Sample topics:
        <ul>
            <li>Alcohol, tobacco, marijuana and other drugs</li>
            <li>Harm reduction and party skills</li>
        </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Sample topics:
        <ul>
            <li>Topic 1</li>
            <li>Topic 2</li>
        </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the smooth scroll jQuery code should not be applied to tabs. So change the smooth scroll jQuery code this way:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not(#tabs ul li a)').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1500);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you, Praveen!